# strophe js receives a single message using with angular 4

Tags: angular, xmpp, ejabberd, strophe.js

I am using Strophe.js to connect with **XMPP** server in **angular4**. connection.addHandler() received a single message. I add this listener after successful connection.

```
connection.addHandler(this.receiveMessage, null, 'message');
```

Please tell what I missing or incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that your `receivedMessage` function returns `true` in order to continue to be called when you receive a new message. If it doesn't return `true`, it will only be called once and you will have to add it again via `connection.addHandler()`.